# Detectar o sistema operacional mobile e redirecionar para uma página em especifico

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, android, ios

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?, gostaria que alguém me orientasse em uma coisa, estou tentando implementar em um site, um botão onde a depender do sistema operacional, ele redireciona para um site.
Ex: Se o celular da pessoa for Android, coloco ele pra redirecionar para a playstore, se for Iphone, coloco para redirecionar para a AppStore, alguém pode me ajudar por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize esta função

```
function descobreOs() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;


    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Windows Phone";
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }


    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

    return "n_sei";
}
```

dai so para debug você faz:

```
alert(descobreOs());
```

Comment: Funcionou!!
Muito obrigado!